# How do I disable the track-change popup in the WMP11 mini-bar?

Tags: windows-media-player

How do I disable the track-change popup in the WMP11 mini-bar?

(Windows XP if it makes a difference)

Answer (score 1):

There is a registry hack to fix that.

Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Preferences`

Create a DWORD named `DeskbandFlyoutTimeout` and set it to `0`

Comment: This works but it also stops the popup appearing when you hover your mouse over the mini-bar in the Windows task bar.

Comment: Yeah, I usually don't need to know which song/video is playing so I didn't mind the trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid this is something that is part of the WMP mini-bar, you can either disable mini-bar all together or use a much better media software like [songbird](http://www.getsongbird.com/) or [winamp](http://www.winamp.com/)